# How to make export csv controller in elixir phoenix framework?

Tags: csv, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a function that make "contacts.csv" like this.

```
def write(people) do
    [["name", "phone_number"]]
    |> Stream.concat(people |> Stream.map(&[&1.name, Formatter.remove_international_code(&1.phone_number)]))
    |> CSV.encode()
    |> Enum.into(File.stream!("contacts.csv"))
end
```

and I want my customer clicks button to download that file. So I did it like this..

In router.ex

```
get "/csv/:id", CsvExportController, :export
```

In controller file

```
def export(conn, %{"id" => phonebook_id}) do
    conn
    |> put_resp_content_type("text/csv")
    |> put_resp_header("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"contacts.csv\"")
    |> send_resp(200, export_contacts_from_phonebook(phonebook_id))
  end

  def export_contacts_from_phonebook(phonebook_id) do
    Contact.get_people(phonebook_id)
    |> CsvFormatter.write()
  end
```

in CsvFormatter.ex

```
def write(people) do
    [["name", "phone_number"]]
    |> Stream.concat(people |> Stream.map(&[&1.name, Formatter.remove_international_code(&1.phone_number)]))
    |> CSV.encode()
    |> Enum.sort()
    |> Enum.into(File.stream!("contacts.csv"))
end
```

and tried but got an error

```
no function clause matching in Plug.Conn.resp/3
```

how can I do this in controller file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
def export(conn, %{"id" => phonebook_id})
  send_download(
    conn,
    {:binary, export_contacts_from_phonebook(phonebook_id)},
    content_type: "application/csv",
    filename: "download.csv"
  )
end
```

in your controller.

Comment: is this controller function? where is body?

Comment: it's in the controller. I edited the answer for clarification. The file content is the second element of the tuple which is the 2nd argument sent to send_download

Comment: see https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#send_download/3 for documentation

Comment: I am still getting errors *no function clause matching in Plug.Conn.resp/3, this function export_contacts_from_phonebook(phonebook_id) export "contacts.csv" in root directory. I updated to show CsvFormatter.write() function.

Comment: You need to be passing the CSV content as a string, looks like you're passing a list. Might need to join with newlines?

Comment: Right I just comment out last function (Enum.into) in CsvFormatter.write() then it works! Thank you